# How to make a relaxation of a 2D surface with LAMMPS

Tags: lammps, surfaces

I would like to perform an energy minimization of a 2D surface without changing the c parameter. I run a :
**fix             1 all box/relax iso 0.0 vmax 0.001**
with
**boundary        p p f**
but it was not accepted as the system is not periodic.

Thank you in advance
Regards

Comment: Try this : fix 1 all box/relax x 0.0 y 0.0

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us! Was the comment by @Pranavkumar helpful?